# Закрыть сайт на реконструкцию

Tags: php

Как лучше закрыть сайт на "реконструкцию"? Т.е. есть сайт, и новая версия этого сайта, на время слияния и залития новой версии сайта, и проверки на правильность слияния необходимо закрыть доступ к сайту рядовым пользователям, но при этом дать доступ для тестирования. Как лучше это организовать?

Comment: Что вы для `deployment'a` используете?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать , использую git , но проблема в том что структура баз немного отличается, поэтому не обойтись обычным мерженм )

Comment: if (!$config['site_run'] == true) {
exit('Сайт на реконструкции');
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тестируйте все на другой машине, паблик не предназначен для тестов.

Проще всего сделайте заглушку, и средствами .htaccess всем кроме вашего внешнего айпи делайте либо редирект либо ответ заглушкой. Для вашего айпи соответственно рабочий .htaccess.

Comment: > Тестируйте все на другой машине, паблик не предназначен для тестов.

новая версия протестирована, но проблема в том, что структура БД поменялась, и будет необходимо после залития провести еще пару нехитрых операций, но которые могут занять некоторое количество времени. и тестировать уже на рабочей БД.

> Проще всего сделайте заглушку, и средствами .htaccess

спасибо, попробую )

Comment: Если база изменилась - переделайте на машине для тестов и дамп залейте в паблик.

Вообще старайтесь готовить обновления так, чтобы не было необходимости в заглушке. Все обновления должны занимать как можно меньшее время. Лучше около нескольких секунд и менее.

Answer (score 5):

- создаем поддомен test.mysyte.com и переливаем тестировочный сайт на него
- этот поддомен закрываем средствами .htaccess на пароль, который раздаем доверенным тестерам
- на основном домене вешаем заглушку на index.php

все ссылки должны быть относительными от хоста, конечно же.

Comment: и тратим еще тучу денег на тестовый домен

Comment: вы невнимательны - я имел ввиду поддомен уже существующего домена, он бесплатен :)

Comment: +, сам так делаю когда меняется код, а не база.

Comment: в зависимости от хостера

Answer (score 0):

Ну index.php закрываешь, а с другой странице даешь доступ своим помеченным пользователям.

Comment: Это не решит проблему если есть внешние ссылки, которые идут не на корень сайта.